# Adding arrays on Nvidia's GPU

Tags: python, gpu, numba

I am learning GPU/Python on Win 10, Intel I7 (3.4 GHz, 16 MB RAM), Nvidia GTX 760 (compute-level = 3.0), latest install of numpy, numba, cuda and related tools. I have three related questions.

The example given below runs slower on the GPU than the CPU! I would like to learn why this is so.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def Add_GPU(a, b):
  return a + b

def Add_CPU(a, b):
  return a + b

def f3():
    # Initialize arrays
    N = 10000000
    A = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float32)
    B = np.ones(A.shape, dtype=A.dtype)
    C = np.empty_like(A, dtype=A.dtype)

    # Add arrays.
    start = timer()
    C = Add_GPU(A, B)
    print("Time Add_GPU:", timer()-start)

    start = timer()
    C = Add_CPU(A, B)
    print("Time Add_CPU:", timer()-start)

f3()
```

Results are:

```
WI - Python> test_GPU
Time Add_GPU: 0.3832171000000001
Time Add_CPU: 0.013704299999999892
```

In the above code, if I replace `@jit` with `@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')`, the compiler says compute-level=3.5 is needed. Please let me know what is going on there.

Is there a table of such requirements? For example, what compute-level would be needed for PyTorch or TensorFlow?

Comment: Your (8 year old) GPU is too old to be supported by any current release of CUDA or any of the Python frameworks that can use a recent release CUDA GPU and toolkit for acceleration. And  your first code snippet isn't running on a GPU at all, it is compiled for your CPU. And it is slower because the time you measure includes the time to compile it. Run it twice and measure the execution time of the second call

Comment: Timing functions can be useful, but only if done properly - look at the standard library `timeit` for easy to use and accurate utility functions.

Comment: On Windows the time granularity function is pretty bad. On my machine this gives such sorted results after ignoring the compilation time: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0065, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156, 0.0156. One can see that timing threshold make the benchmark totally flawed (independently of calling `Add_CPU` or `Add_GPU` (which does not use the GPU). Besides this, using the GPU implementation is bound to be slower because of PCI+memory transfers while the CPU implementation only pay memory transfers.

Comment: I also forgot to mention "Intel i7" processors does not mean much as it is [a brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core). The architecture actually matters much more. Indeed, an i7 Bloomfield (13-year old) processor will definitively be much slower than an i7 Rocket Lake (released this year) and likely even slower than an i5 Rocket Lake. The exact model also matters a bit as all i7 Rocket Lake processors are not strictly equivalent. It would be a bit like saying you use an Nvidia GTX (or let say GT) without mentioning the 760.

Comment: All three comments are useful and informative. I learned something about my GTX card, CUDA, and timers in Python. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the guidance provided by the commenters and additional web searches, I have been able to use the GTX 760 card (compute ability = 3.0) as follows. The key has been to find compatible earlier versions of software.

1. Uninstall all Nvidia's software except the video driver (through Windows).
2. Uninstall Python packages (if already installed):
   `conda uninstall numba cudatoolkit`
3. Install cudatoolkit V 10.2 by downloading from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive.
4. Install Python packages to use pytorch functional:

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit==10.2.89
conda install numba=0.50
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 -c pytorchy
pip install cupy-cuda102
```

I posted the commands in case someone else is in a similar situation. The above installation is not as powerful as the most current, but it allows me to learn and experiment on an humble GTX card. The examples given in numba documentation now work - no error messages.